# Why are design intuitions restricted to certain areas of life, and in those areas so popular?

Tags: philosophy-of-design

Why are our design intuitions limited to events that we find significant?

No one is thinking that God is sending down a sign if you wake up at a certain time tomorrow, or if the order number for your breakfast today was #83828, or if your friend called you at 8:32 PM today. And yet, if you met your friend many years after cutting contact in the same place you met him last time, you might start pondering about some divine designer making it happen as such.

Why do many assume that a designer who likes to create events that are important to your life is more likely to exist that one who creates events that are insignificant to you? Why is this widespread intuition so common and what is the philosophical, if any, basis for it?

Comment: As someone on the schizophrenia spectrum who spent ten years trying to justify my religious beliefs (to myself), I would say that design intuitions actually do come up while reviewing everyday occurrences. One time I was reading the SEP and they talked about a poem about a vase or something in the article, and the fantasy book I was reading brought up the same poem, and I thought it was a sign ‍♂️

Comment: What religion were you brought up in? @KristianBerry That is very interesting. I have severe OCD which can be a precursor to schizophrenia. I also spent about a decade trying to justify them until I stumbled upon philosophy and finally realized that the arguments were defunct. My hypothesis is that people like us are captured by emotional reasoning. We might notice that a certain belief has no substance or argument behind it but we may not feel a sense of “intuitive completeness”. It is this lack of completeness that makes us seek further inquiry when none needs to be made.

Comment: My parents were agnostic (Dad) and atheist (Mom), although with ex-Catholic baggage. Supposedly my dad's own mom was ethnically Jewish but also Irish, IDK but so around the age of 17 I was part of a group called Tikkun Olam, a left-wing Jewish-Palestinian reconciliation program. I sort of considered Islam at one point, but when I was about 26 I read Anselm's *Cur Deus Homo* and somehow that convinced me that Jesus was actually God Incarnate. And it went this way for ten years, until about half a year ago, when my ethical beliefs sharpened to where I couldn't believe in the Incarnation anymore.

Comment: All intuitions are so limited for the trivial reason that we generally pay more attention to what is significant to us. This is called personal relevance bias and there is nothing specific to design about it. Nor does it imply that a designer is not behind other events as well (indeed, it is assumed that he is behind events significant to others, for instance), they are just paid less attention to.

Comment: I think you're confusing philosophy with psychology.

Comment: Thinking that God is in charge of small things feels so... petty. Like the ultimate helicopter parent. Most people have enough experience with the randomness of reality to find the idea of someone in charge of any of it absurd, or often, enraging.

Comment: The answer can be found in an old movie, remade, curse me memory, in the 2000s. Good luck! There are at least 2 thingies -  hope & *veritas* - and they went ta bed and we got ID.

Comment: "Why do many assume that a designer who likes to create events that are important to your life is more likely to exist that one who creates events that are insignificant to you?" -- Probably the same reason that some people who suffer from chronic depression feel that God is punishing them.

Comment: Consider https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taxicab_number The short answer is: apophenia. We seek patterns.

Answer (score 2):

I think the question you have posed is a very interesting one, and it can be generalised to asking why it is that humans have a tendency to believe in religion, superstitions, the supernatural, UFOs and so on. From a Darwinian perspective, we would have to suppose that the tendency could be there for one of two very general reasons: either it is an advantage that increases the chance of survival, or it is a harmless side-effect that has never triggered any deselection mechanism. Given the magnitude of the effects that irrational beliefs have on human behaviour, I find it hard to imagine that the tendency is some neutral side effect- instead, I imagine that it must have played a role in ensuring the survival of humans who possessed it. There are many modern philosophers who have shared that view and explored its implications, writing about what they consider to be obvious evolutionary advantages of religious tendencies in terms of social cohesion. Personally, I can recall many occasions as a child on which various adults went about conditioning my behaviour by instilling all kinds of fears into me with tales about god, witches, Father Christmas, angels, and heaven knows what other nonsense, so clearly a tendency to believe such rubbish is one that can be put to good use.

Comment: Summary? - it doesn't matter why you do the right thing, as long as you do it. So a crazy reason is just as useful as a rational reason.

Comment: This perspective is formalised in Donald Hoffman's 'Evolutionary Argument Against Reality' https://www.quantamagazine.org/the-evolutionary-argument-against-reality-20160421/

Answer (score 0):

I'd like to additional evidence to Macro Ocram's answer with reference to a book called "Sapiens" by Yuval Noah Hariri in Chapter-2,

> As the number of chimpanzees in a troop increases, the social order destabilises, eventually leading to a rupture and the formation of a new troop by some of the animals. Only in a handful of cases have zoologists observed groups larger than a hundred. Separate groups seldom cooperate, and tend to compete for territory and food. Researchers have documented prolonged warfare between groups, and even one case of ‘genocidal’ activity in which one troop systematically slaughtered most members of a neighbouring band.
>
> ....
>
> In the wake of the Cognitive Revolution, gossip helped Homo sapiens to form larger and more stable bands. But even gossip has its limits. Sociological research has shown that the maximum ‘natural’ size of a group bonded by gossip is about 150 individuals. Most people can neither intimately know, nor gossip eʃectively about, more than 150 human beings. Even today, a critical threshold in human organisations falls somewhere around this magic number. Below this threshold, communities, businesses, social networks and military units can maintain themselves based mainly on intimate acquaintance and rumour-mongering. There is no need for formal ranks, titles and law books to keep order. 3 A platoon of thirty soldiers or even a company of a hundred soldiers can function well on the basis of intimate relations, with a minimum of formal discipline. A well-respected sergeant can become ‘king of the company and exercise authority even over commissioned oɽcers. A small family business can survive and ɻourish without a board of directors, a CEO or an accounting department
>
> But once the threshold of 150 individuals is crossed, things can no longer work that way. You cannot run a division with thousands of soldiers the same way you run a platoon. Successful family businesses usually face a crisis when they grow larger and hire more personnel. If they cannot reinvent themselves, they go bust. How did Homo sapiens manage to cross this critical threshold, eventually founding cities comprising tens of thousands of inhabitants and empires ruling hundreds of millions? The secret was probably the appearance of ɹction. Large numbers of strangers can cooperate successfully by believing in common myths.

There is probably more information regarding this topic in the book, but I haven't read much into this book.